# How are the participants of a Ring Signature selected?

Tags: transaction-data, ring-signatures, ringsize, outputs

If I understand correctly, the participants of a ring signature will be just other outputs. But I don't understand the criteria for selecting those outputs.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand correctly, the participants of a ring signature will be just other outputs.

Correct. Well, more specifically also  *commitments*.

> But I don't understand the criteria for selecting those outputs.

Aside from decoy outputs needing to be at least 10 blocks confirmed (e.g. spendable), the decoy selection algorithm is designed to select outputs from across the blockchain based on observed spending patterns, as recommended in [Möser et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04299/).